# SOAP connection with Royal Mail, Could not connect to host

Tags: php, api, soap, connection

I'm trying to connect to Royal Mail shipping API, but I'm receiving the famous Could not connect to host.

```
$api_password = "****";
$api_username = "****";
$api_application_id = "****";
$api_service_type = "D";
$api_service_code = "SD1";
$api_service_format = "";
$api_certificate_passphrase = "****";
                    $time = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
                    $created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
                    $nonce = mt_rand();
                    $nonce_date_pwd = xyz(copy from sample);
                    $passwordDigest = zyz(copy from sample);
                    $ENCODEDNONCE = zyz(copy from sample);

                    $soapclient_options = array();
                    $soapclient_options['cache_wsdl'] = 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE';
                    $soapclient_options['local_cert'] = "CA2+Splash+Felipe+RM10001654+usr.p12";
                    $soapclient_options['passphrase'] = $api_certificate_passphrase;
                    $soapclient_options['trace'] = true;
                    $soapclient_options['ssl_method'] = 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3';
                    $soapclient_options['location'] = '****';
                    //launch soap client
                    $client = new SoapClient("SAPI/ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl", $soapclient_options);
                    $client->__setLocation($soapclient_options['location']);
```

(setting header)

```
$HeaderObject = new SoapVar( $HeaderObjectXML, XSD_ANYXML );

            //push soap header
    $header = new SoapHeader( 'oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $HeaderObject );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

(setting request part)

```
if($api_service_enhancements != "") {
                        $request['requestedShipment']['serviceEnhancements'] = array('enhancementType' => array('serviceEnhancementCode' => array('code' => $api_service_enhancements)));
        }

    //try make the call
            try {
                        $response = $client->__soapCall('createShipment', array($request), array('soapaction' => '***api-link***') );


            }           catch (Exception $e) {

                        //catch the error message and echo the last request for debug
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
                        die;
            }
```

Is it correct the way I'm setting the connection and the local cert?
Is any information I'm missing?
Thanks & Regards

Comment: I have the exact same problem - did you get past this problem Michael, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Follow my final code :) this one works for sure. Even have the retry in case the server is buzy, enjoy.

```
<?php
//ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '1'); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
class royalmaillabelRequest
{
    private $apiapplicationid = "insert urs";
    private $api_password = "insert urs"; 
    private $api_username = "insert urs"; //"rxxxxxAPI"
    private $api_certificate_passphrase = "insert urs";
    private $locationforrequest = 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding'; //live 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping' onbording 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding'
    private $api_service_enhancements = "";

    private function preparerequest(){

        //PASSWORD DIGEST
        $time = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
                $created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
                $nonce = mt_rand();
                $nonce_date_pwd = xyz(copy from sample);
            $passwordDigest = nyz(copy from sample);
            $ENCODEDNONCE = (copy from sample);

            //SET CONNECTION DETAILS

            $soapclient_options = array();
                $soapclient_options['cache_wsdl'] = 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE';
                $soapclient_options['stream_context'] = stream_context_create(
                                                    array('http'=>
                                                        array(
                                                            'protocol_version'=>'1.0'
                                                            , 'header' => 'Connection: Close'
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                );
                $soapclient_options['local_cert'] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/certificate.pem";
                $soapclient_options['passphrase'] = $this->api_certificate_passphrase;
                $soapclient_options['trace'] = true;
                $soapclient_options['ssl_method'] = 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3';
                $soapclient_options['location'] = $this->locationforrequest;
                $soapclient_options['soap_version'] = 'SOAP_1_1';

                //launch soap client
                $client = new SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__) . "/SAPI/ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl", $soapclient_options);
                $client->__setLocation($soapclient_options['location']);

                //headers needed for royal mail//D8D094Fd2716E3Es142588808s317
        $HeaderObjectXML  = '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                                          xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                               <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-D8D094FC22716E3EDE14258880881317">
                                  <wsse:Username>'.$this->api_username.'</wsse:Username>
                                  <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'.$passwordDigest.'</wsse:Password>
                                  <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'.$ENCODEDNONCE.'</wsse:Nonce>
                                  <wsu:Created>'.$created.'</wsu:Created>
                               </wsse:UsernameToken>
                           </wsse:Security>'; 
        //push the header into soap
        $HeaderObject = new SoapVar( $HeaderObjectXML, XSD_ANYXML );                           
        //push soap header
        $header = new SoapHeader( 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $HeaderObject );
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
        return $client;

    }

    public function CreateShippiment($data){

        $request = $this->buildCreateshippiment($data);
        $type    = 'createShipment';

        return $this->makerequest($type, $request);


    }
    public function PrintLabel($shipmentNumber,$order_tracking_id){

        $time = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
        $request = array(
                'integrationHeader' => array(
                    'dateTime' => $time,
                    'version' => '2',
                    'identification' => array(
                        'applicationId' => $this->apiapplicationid,
                        'transactionId' => $order_tracking_id
                    )
                ),
                'shipmentNumber' => $shipmentNumber,
                'outputFormat' => 'PDF',
        );
        $type = 'printLabel';
        $response = $this->makerequest($type, $request);
        return $response->label;

    }

    private function makerequest($type, $request){

        $client = $this->preparerequest();
        $response = false;
        $times = 1;

        while(true){

            try {
                            $response = $client->__soapCall( $type, array($request), array('soapaction' => $this->locationforrequest) );

                           // echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";
                            break;

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                            print_r($e);
                            if($e->detail->exceptionDetails->exceptionCode == "E0010" && $times <= 25){

                        sleep(1.5);                     
                        $times++;
                        continue;                       

                            }else{
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                                echo "<pre>";
                                print_r($e->detail);
                                echo $client->__getLastResponse();
                                echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";
                                break;

                            }           

                }

                break;
            }
            return $response;
    }

    private function buildCreateshippiment($data2) {

            $time = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

            $data = new ArrayObject();
            foreach ($data2 as $key => $value)
            {
                $data->$key = $value;
            }


            $request = array(
                'integrationHeader' => array(
                    'dateTime' => $time,
                    'version' => '2',
                    'identification' => array(
                        'applicationId' => $this->apiapplicationid,
                        'transactionId' => $data->order_tracking_id
                    )
                ),
                'requestedShipment' => array(
                                            'shipmentType' => array('code' => 'Delivery'),
                                            'serviceOccurrence' => 1,
                                            'serviceType' => array('code' => $data->api_service_type),
                                            'serviceOffering' => array('serviceOfferingCode' => array('code' => $data->api_service_code)),
                                            'serviceFormat' => array('serviceFormatCode' => array('code' => $data->api_service_format)),
                                            'shippingDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                            'recipientContact' => array('name' => $data->shipping_name, 'complementaryName' => $data->shipping_company),
                                            'recipientAddress' => array('addressLine1' => $data->shipping_address1,  'addressLine2' => $data->shipping_address2, 'postTown' => $data->shipping_town, 'postcode' => $data->shipping_postcode),
                                            'items' => array('item' => array(
                                                                'numberOfItems' => $data->order_tracking_boxes,
                                                                'weight' => array( 'unitOfMeasure' => array('unitOfMeasureCode' => array('code' => 'g')),
                                                                'value' => $data->order_tracking_weight,
                                                                                 )
                                                                            )
                                                            ),
                                            //'signature' => 0,

                )
            );

        if($data->api_service_enhancements == 6 && $data->api_service_type == 1){
                    $request['requestedShipment']['serviceEnhancements'] = array('enhancementType' => array('serviceEnhancementCode' => array('code' => $data->api_service_enhancements)));
            }

            return $request;

    }






}
```

Comment: if this does not work you should try call them and say that you think there's an error with the onboarding server and ask if you can try to connect on live.

Comment: $request = new royalmaillabelRequest();
$response = $request->CreateShippiment($array);

Comment: and make your certificate .pem, think was it.

Comment: Awesome stuff Michael! I will give this a go at some point today - really appreciate the effort from yourself +1

Comment: just wondered - my certificate was received by Royal Mail in this format - 
CA2+Company-Name+Firstname-Lastname+RM10001234+usr.p12.

Should I just rename this to certificate.pem? I'll probably have to phone them as they seem slow on email

Comment: Ok... i am getting closer :) their 'documentation' has commands to create 3 *.pem files (cacert.pem, mycert.pem & mykey.pem). I've created the files but not quite sure what to do next

Comment: You just need one of those keys, just change in the code for the location of one of the new ones and it should work. And when you send a email aways call asking them to reply LOL.

Comment: I don't believe I can contact you directly through Stackoverflow - Royal Mail aren't much help on this at all (clearly outsourcing their work..) I have finally received the API login details from RM this week & setup the certificate locally on my machine.

I have created the 3 *.pem files that the documentation states & linked the file named 'cacert.pem' in the 'local_cert' within the soapclient options array.

No matter what I do I am always getting an 'Could not connect to host' message.

Comment: All sorted... RM are a pain in the .... Thanks for the code it is really really useful!! Good work my friend!

Comment: Hi @michaelriis - do you have an example of the array you send to CreateShippiment so I can test this easily? Thanks for all the hard work on the code, i'm just trying this for the first time today.

Comment: Okay, that's just me being lazy - I found an example xml request and built the order array but i'm getting 'Could not connect to host' - what did you do @Zabs to get it working please?

Comment: Here's the array in case anyone else is lazy like me! ;) `$array = array(
 'order_tracking_id' => '0000000006',
 'api_service_type' => '1',
 'api_service_code' => 'CRL',
 'api_service_format' => 'P',
 'shipping_name' => 'Mr Tom Smith',
 'shipping_company' => 'Department 98',
 'shipping_address1' => '3 Vantage Walk',
 'shipping_address2' => '',
 'shipping_town' => 'Hastings',
 'shipping_postcode' => 'TN38 0YP',
 'order_tracking_boxes' => '1',
 'order_tracking_weight' => '100'
);`

Comment: @Ashley i can't look into this right now but try this post - the code by michael should work, let me know if you still have problems.
Remember to setup up the certs too, it maybe the process when you are creating the *.pem & cert files. I made a mistake in this initially, but then re-did the process carefully & it worked.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986068/soap-connection-with-royal-mail-could-not-connect-to-host/32590275#32590275

Comment: I made the file from `% openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -out cacert.pem` and am including it in the code above like so: `$soapclient_options['local_cert'] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cacert.pem";`

Comment: Do you need to use mycert.pem and mykey.pem somehow? Micheal writes above that you just need one.

Comment: Just in case anybody is reading this thread, I found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101153/royal-mail-shipping-api-soap-connection-pem-certificates-query - which is to combine the mycert and mykey into a single file and use that

Answer (score 0):

docs.oasis-open.org is slow and doesn't respond in time.

Download `oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd` and modify `ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl` to use local version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I made the changes you said as you can see in the edit I did, but the page still returning Could not connect to host

Comment: did you get around your issues?

Comment: I am having the VERY same problem.. did you get around the problem?

Comment: @Zabs You should be able to use `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);` to wait 2 minutes for response, and rely on wsdl caching so next requests are faster.

Comment: added a bounty - i'm working on a Royal Mail integration now and have the same problems as the OP.

Comment: When I was doing it they had an error with the onboarding server, so when they gave me access to live everything went fine

Answer (score 0):

Your location looks wrong..

```
$soapclient_options['location'] = '****';
```

Shouldn't this look like this..

```
$soapclient_options['location'] = 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding';
```