# Output a standard Base64 Encoded stream into PDF format (PHP)

Tags: php, api, pdf, stream, base64

I am using the Royal Mail Shipping API to generate printed PDF labels, my PHP SoapClient returns a valid response shown below (only shown the initial response as the whole response is huge).

```
%PDF-1.7 %äãÏÒ 4 0 obj <> stream xœ endstream endobj 3 0 obj 8 endobj 9 0 obj <> stream xÚí]bì*¤Höýoübƒ¤Æ-q²É>ø%Íë‚ÔFÒ<1ÆoÌúÝú¯ý?1Æ%Èa9Ò4QÌ!}üŠ ÆãS€ZÿŸ2Mô¨H}üÃŸÇcŒ˜Z´½\¡´üý’y©1Æø$¨RÓd°úø’ÆÄŒ1Ægð´ ¨Š'ª°Z¾MCF1Æ}¥/¨{d˜ZQ•†Þ7Æ_P¢õ‘ kjŒ1.J¦ê”ÕÑŽ©,ž‹1ÆãNÿÅIü{}L%üÄcŒÑS Þª€êÁI”ÀÅÃcŒcHÚsïuP5Ð4Æ .ê2¤mbŒ1vU¼vè:ž>Æ<´¾1ÆØTŠûfÓ¢œÆcTŒ³wGF1Æ
```

Can anyone suggest the best method to 'convert' this Base64 encoded PDF label correctly so I can physically download this to the browser. My code below downloads the PDF file but when I attempt to open this the filesize is always 57kb and I returns the following message in Acrobat Reader

```
"There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."
```

My code is as follows:

```
$rm = new RoyalMailLabelRequest();
// provide shipment number, order tracking id, output format (e.g PDF/PNG)
$response = $rm->PrintLabel('TTT000358756GB', '276831601444829801', 'PDF');

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="doc-'.$document.'.pdf"');
$data = base64_decode($response);
file_put_contents('pdf/label.pdf', $data);
```

### UPDATE

When I try to echo the decoded response I get the following... not sure what is happening with this one.. odd.

```
$response = $rm->PrintLabel('TTT000358756GB', '276831601444829801', 'PDF');
$data = base64_decode($response);
echo $data;exit;
```

Echo'd $data response after being base64_decoded

```
<1uï(n?Ëzx-‡}üX¥µêÿV­x7œ¡×¬¶·š›
```

I've also added the full base64_encode response that is returned by my code here on pastebin if it helps anyone 
http://pastebin.com/JEtmRURK

Comment: Don't you want to just `echo $data`? You don't appear to be outputting the PDF file contents to the browser.

Comment: Sorry - i noticed a mistake in the code above, the file_put_contents gets the decoded response (as the var $data).
I've tried echo'ing $data but to no avail :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted - been a very long day.

I didn't need to decode the response in the end so the following will work (hopefully it helps someone else doing the API integration)

```
function PrintLabelRequest($shipmentNumber, $transactionId)
{
   $rm = new RoyalMailLabelRequest();

   // function from library returns a response using SOAP
   $response = $rm->PrintLabel($shipmentNumber, $transactionId);

   // name the file & saved this label as a PDF in the following folder
   $filename = 'printedlabel-' . $shipmentNumber;
   file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/labels/'. $filename .'.pdf', $response);
}
```

Comment: Just seen [your message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101153/royal-mail-shipping-api-soap-connection-pem-certificates-query#comment54068667_33101532) - you've sorted your issue fully?

Comment: Yep all working now thanks for getting back to me - it wasn't worth asking Royal Mail they take too long to respond