# Royal Mail Shipping API - SOAP connection & pem/certificates query

Tags: php, ssl, soap-client, digital-certificate, pem

I am trying to setup the Royal Mail Shipping API (if anyone has any experience of this i'd be grateful if you could assist).

In the documentation they provide I need to download a certificate (a .p12 file) & import this onto my Windows machine - this is pretty straightforward using the 'Certificate Import Wizard'. Once it gets to the "Set Security Level' I must select **High** & this will request permission with a password each time this is used.

In Internet Explorer in 'Internet Options' within the Content tab I can view the Certificates and can clearly see that this certificate has been imported and hasn't expired.

The next step is to **extract the certificate components**, here I have to run the three following commands using OpenSSL to generate the .pem files.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -out cacert.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out mycert.pem
$ openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out mykey.pem
```

The documentation states the **cacert.pem file can be directly referenced by an application using the file itself**, which I believe I have done within my PHP script however it isn't clear where I should put the other **mycert & mykey pem files**.

The documentation states the following in regards to this :-

> How an application passes the issued client SSL certificate when establishing an SSL network connection to is application and environment dependent but it would essentially need to access both the "mycert.pem" and "mykey.pem" file, or in some cases, a single combined file containing both cert and key.

So nowhere does it say how these two files are used by the application, at the moment I've just left them in the same directory as the cacert.pem file.

If I try to access the url https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding directly from the browser, it asks for me to select a certificate, I select this & then enter the correct password when it asks to 'Grant or deny permission to use this key'. Once I enter the correct password the following page appears - can anyone confirm if this would mean the issue is at my end OR something that Royal Mail hasn't configured correctly at their end.

[image]

In addition to this, the actual PHP script that I have that is used to send SOAP requests to the Shipping API isn't working (probably related to everything above).

Within my PHP script the soapclient options are set up as follows:

```
$soapclient_options['cache_wsdl'] = 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE'; 
$soapclient_options['local_cert'] = 'certs/cacert.pem';
$soapclient_options['passphrase'] = $api_certificate_passphrase;
$soapclient_options['trace'] = true;
$soapclient_options['ssl_method'] = 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3';
$soapclient_options['location'] = 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding';

$client = new SoapClient('SAPI/ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl', $soapclient_options);
$client->__setLocation($soapclient_options['location']);
```

When I run the PHP script (this is basically the same code that Royal Mail provide themselves with my own personal API login details) I get the following message in the browser:

```
Could not connect to host 
REQUEST: email@yoursite.co.ukAPI rngfJ+4dt4Gt855a5pr6u38i3B4= ODcwMTE5Nzc3 2015-10-13T11:02:20Z 2015-10-13T11:02:201.00526348001DeliveryDSD12015-10-13bobSS23, Some AvenueLondonE10g1000000
```

Obviously this cannot connect to the host for some unknown reason, the latter is simply the request that was sent. The rest of the PHP script is exactly the same as the Royal Mail's script they sent to me & have confirmed is used by others and working fine.

I am working in a WAMP environment although the eventual code will be in a Linux environment. **Can anyone help** I am really getting baffled & Royal Mail themselves haven't been able to provide any solid technical support yet.

#### UPDATE

This is the full error message displayed in the browser (i've changed the email address for security purposes)

```
Invalid Request REQUEST: myemail@company.co.ukAPI dgCW98Vqw3ladYgPPpNialODhvI= MTMzMjE1NjM4 2015-10-13T13:25:30Z 2015-10-13T13:25:302.00526348001DeliveryDSD12015-10-13Jon DoeSS23, Some RoadLondonE10g1000000
```

> I've merged the two pem files into a single file called 'bundle.pem' & referenced this in the 'local_cert' variable for the SoapClient & BINGO this is now connecting. This now longer shows the **Could not connect** but states an 'Invalid Request' instead, so at least now this is connecting and giving me a different error.

My entire PHP script is below:

```
<?php

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',1);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',1);

$api_password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx!";
$api_username = "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.co.ukAPI";
$api_application_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$api_service_type = "D";
$api_service_code = "SD1";
$api_service_format = "";
$api_certificate_passphrase = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$api_service_enhancements = "";

$data = new ArrayObject();
$data->order_tracking_id = "";
$data->shipping_name = "Jon Doe";
$data->shipping_company = "SS";
$data->shipping_address1 = "23, Some Road"; 
$data->shipping_address2 = "";
$data->shipping_town = "London";
$data->shipping_postcode = "E1";
$data->order_tracking_boxes = "0";
$data->order_tracking_weight = "1000";    

$time = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
$created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$nonce = mt_rand();
$nonce_date_pwd = pack("A*",$nonce) . pack("A*",$created) . pack("H*", sha1($api_password));
$passwordDigest = base64_encode(pack('H*',sha1($nonce_date_pwd)));
$ENCODEDNONCE = base64_encode($nonce);


$soapclient_options = array(); 
$soapclient_options['cache_wsdl'] = 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE'; 
$soapclient_options['local_cert'] = 'royalmail/cert/bundle.pem';
$soapclient_options['passphrase'] = $api_certificate_passphrase;
$soapclient_options['trace'] = true;
$soapclient_options['ssl_method'] = 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3';
$soapclient_options['exceptions'] = true;
$soapclient_options['location'] = 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding';

//launch soap client
$client = new SoapClient('royalmail/ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl', $soapclient_options);
$client->__setLocation($soapclient_options['location']);

//headers needed for royal mail
$HeaderObjectXML  = '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-000">
              <wsse:Username>'.$api_username.'</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'.$passwordDigest.'</wsse:Password>
              <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'.$ENCODEDNONCE.'</wsse:Nonce>
              <wsu:Created>'.$created.'</wsu:Created>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
       </wsse:Security>';

//push the header into soap
$HeaderObject = new SoapVar( $HeaderObjectXML, XSD_ANYXML );

//push soap header
$header = new SoapHeader( 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $HeaderObject );
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

//build the request
$request = array(
    'integrationHeader' => array(
        'dateTime' => $time,
        'version' => '1.0',
        'identification' => array(
            'applicationId' => $api_application_id,
            'transactionId' => $data->order_tracking_id
        )
    ),
    'requestedShipment' => array(
                                'shipmentType' => array('code' => 'Delivery'),
                                'serviceOccurence' => '1',
                                'serviceType' => array('code' => $api_service_type),
                                'serviceOffering' => array('serviceOfferingCode' => array('code' => $api_service_code)),
                                'serviceFormat' => array('serviceFormatCode' => array('code' => $api_service_format)),
                                'shippingDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                'recipientContact' => array('name' => $data->shipping_name, 'complementaryName' => $data->shipping_company),
                                'recipientAddress' => array('addressLine1' => $data->shipping_address1,  'addressLine2' => $data->shipping_address2, 'postTown' => $data->shipping_town, 'postcode' => $data->shipping_postcode),
                                'items' => array('item' => array(
                                            'numberOfItems' => $data->order_tracking_boxes,
                                            'weight' => array( 'unitOfMeasure' => array('unitOfMeasureCode' => array('code' => 'g')), 'value' => ($data->order_tracking_weight*1000) //weight of each individual item
                                                             )
                                                                )
                                                )
                                )               
);


//if any enhancements, add it into the array
if($api_service_enhancements != "") {
    $request['requestedShipment']['serviceEnhancements'] = array('enhancementType' => array('serviceEnhancementCode' => array('code' => $api_service_enhancements)));
}

//try make the call
try { 
    $response = $client->__soapCall( 'createShipment', array($request), array('soapaction' => 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding') );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //catch the error message and echo the last request for debug
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    echo " REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    die;
}

//check for any errors
if(isset($response->integrationFooter->errors)) { 
    $build = "";

    //check it wasn't a single error message
    if(isset($response->integrationFooter->errors->error->errorCode)) { 
        $build .= $output_error->errorCode.": ".$output_error->errorDescription."<br/>"; 
    } else {
        //loop out each error message, throw exception will be added ehre
        foreach($response->integrationFooter->errors->error as $output_error) { 
            $build .= $output_error->errorCode.": ".$output_error->errorDescription."<br/>";
        }
    }

    echo $build; die;

}

print_r($response);

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
die;            
?>
```

Just for additional clarity I've added a dump of the $request variable just before it reaches the try/catch block (note this is kinda long).

```
Array
(
    [integrationHeader] => Array
        (
        [dateTime] => 2015-10-13T13:34:44
        [version] => 1.0
        [identification] => Array
            (
                [applicationId] => 0526348001
                [transactionId] => 
            )

    )

[requestedShipment] => Array
    (
        [shipmentType] => Array
            (
                [code] => Delivery
            )

        [serviceOccurence] => 1
        [serviceType] => Array
            (
                [code] => D
            )

        [serviceOffering] => Array
            (
                [serviceOfferingCode] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => SD1
                    )

            )

        [serviceFormat] => Array
            (
                [serviceFormatCode] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => 
                    )

            )

        [shippingDate] => 2015-10-13
        [recipientContact] => Array
            (
                [name] => Jon Doe
                [complementaryName] => SS
            )

        [recipientAddress] => Array
            (
                [addressLine1] => 23, Some Road
                [addressLine2] => 
                [postTown] => London
                [postcode] => E1
            )

        [items] => Array
            (
                [item] => Array
                    (
                        [numberOfItems] => 0
                        [weight] => Array
                            (
                                [unitOfMeasure] => Array
                                    (
                                        [unitOfMeasureCode] => Array
                                            (
                                                [code] => g
                                            )

                                    )

                                [value] => 1000000
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: I've literally just finished integrating their Shipping API v2 where I work, I can assist. 5 minutes.

Comment: you my friend are a star :-)

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, accessing the https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding directly will not work, because it's only accessible via the API.

With Royal Mail, do you have all of the CDM files and WSDL files? Make sure the CDM files are in the same directory as the WSDL files.

Here's what I did when working with the API;

```
$client = new SoapClient("/royalmail/ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl", array(
                                                    'trace' => 1,
                                                    'location'   => $location, //https://api.royalmail.com/shipping
                                                    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                                    'local_cert' => '/royalmail/cert/cert.pem',
                                                    'passphrase' => 'xxx',
                                                    'exceptions' => true
                                                ));
```

Then, when it came to actually making the connection, I did something like this:

```
    $password = 'xxx';

    $date = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $nonce = mt_rand();
    $nonce_date_pwd = pack("A*",$nonce) . pack("A*",$date) . pack("H*", sha1($password));
    $encoded_password = base64_encode(pack('H*',sha1($nonce_date_pwd)));
    $encoded_nonce = base64_encode($nonce);

    $HeaderObjectXML  = '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                              xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-0000">
                      <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
                      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">' . $encoded_password . '</wsse:Password>
                      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">' . $encoded_nonce . '</wsse:Nonce>
                      <wsu:Created>'.$date.'</wsu:Created>
                   </wsse:UsernameToken>
               </wsse:Security>';

    $HeaderObject = new SoapVar( $HeaderObjectXML, XSD_ANYXML );

    $header = new SoapHeader( 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $HeaderObject );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders( $header );

    $request = array('the shipment request');

    try {
        $client->__soapCall( 'createShipment', array($request) );
    }
    catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
       print_r($soapFault);
    }
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

Try this request

I *think* you need to use Version 2 for that Service Occurrence, if I remember rightly. Also, just...formatting. Makes it easier to debug.

```
$request = Array(

    'integrationHeader' => array(
        'dateTime' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
        'version' => '2',
        'identification' => array(
            'applicationId' => $api_application_id,
            'transactionId' => $data->order_tracking_id
        ),

    ),

    'requestedShipment' => array(   
        'shipmentType' => array(
            'code' => 'Delivery'
        ),
    'serviceOccurrence' => 1,
        'serviceType' => array(
            'code' => $api_service_type
        ),
        'serviceOffering' => array(
            'serviceOfferingCode' => array(
                'code' => $api_service_code
            )
        ),
        'serviceFormat' => array(
            'serviceFormatCode' => array(
                'code' => $api_service_format
            )
        ),
        'shippingDate' => gmdate('Y-m-d'),
        'recipientContact' => array(
            'name' => $data->shipping_name,
            'complementaryName' => $data->shipping_company
        ),
        'recipientAddress' => array(
            'addressLine1' => $data->shipping_address1,
            'addressLine2' => $data->shipping_address2,
            'postTown' => $data->shipping_town,
            'postcode' => $data->shipping_postcode
        ),
        'items' => array(
            'item' => array(
                'numberOfItems' => $data->order_tracking_boxes,
                'weight' => array(
                    'unitOfMeasure' => array(
                        'unitOfMeasureCode' => array(
                            'code' => 'g'
                        )
                    ),
                    'value' => ($data->order_tracking_weight*1000)
                )
            )
        )

    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks will try this out - you guys are more helpful than Royal Mail themselves :-)

P.S loving the 'illegalPigeon' username, made me chuckle :)

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it works out and if you need an example request! Royal Mail were useless for me, too, so I came up with the above and it worked fine :)

Comment: Thanks - Your local_cert is 'cert.pem' i only have files names 'cacert', 'mycert' & 'mykey' - is there a fourth .pem file i have missed out on?

Comment: That's just the way I named mine. Sorry, should have pointed that out. Rename it to whatever your .pem file is called.

Comment: Oh ok thanks - is your cert.pem file just the contents of both mycert.pem & mykey.pem merged into a single file called 'cert.pem' ?

Comment: Correct. If you use the above code and change some of the parameters to match your details/paths, run it and let me know if you get an error :)

Comment: Excellent - i'm getting an error but its a different one now (invalid request) but I am confident its now at least connecting to the API at last :-) i'll keep debugging this to find the issue... almost there (thanks guys)

Comment: If you post the error up, I'll happily edit my post to help!

Comment: Thanks - i've posted the message & the full PHP script that I am using on WAMP localhost.

Comment: Sorry about that - i've posted the full error message that I see in the browser now (just changed the email address for security purposes) everything else is the same

Comment: the formatting came right from royal mail's own sample code :) I've added your cleaned up $request array but still get the same 'Invalid Request'. I'll keep at it as i'm almost there

Comment: The service format code is empty, also try this: $api_service_format = "P";

Comment: You may also need a `customerReference` or a `senderReference` for more accurate billing...

Comment: @IllegalPigeon i've changed the $api_service_format to 'P' but same the problem persists. Would my information i've passed via the $data ArrayObject be making this invalid somehow do you think?

at ʰᵈˑi've not come across customerReference or senderReference - i'll have a look into that in the docs.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be causing the issue. It's also worth noting that the amount of items is set to "0". You might want to make that at least 1. The RoyalMail API is very temperamental. Also, the customerReference and senderReference won't be causing the issue. Might be worth looking in to them AFTER this issue is solved, just to not make it worse and have less to debug!

Comment: I have another word for the Royal Mail API :-)
Tried changing the items to 1 and the 'Invalid Request' persists, i'll ignore the customerReference/senderReference for the time being as its unrelated to this issue. I'll contact RM and see what they come up with regards to my invalid request.

Comment: GUYS! Fantastic.. sorted it... 
In combination with the *.pem stuff & the api service variables i wasn't aware of & the fact that RM own 'sample' code for some reason had logic like this..
($data->order_tracking_weight * 1000) .... #wtf

Thanks guys!!!  I really want to accept BOTH answers as BOTH help me get this working and gave me 1000 times better understanding than from Royal Mail themselves.

Comment: No worries. I've worked with Royal Mail, too, and they are a pain. Their combination of sloppy error reporting and temperamental API causes havoc.

Comment: @IllegalPigeon would you happen to be able to shed any light on this matter (Shipping API related also)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127790/output-a-standard-base64-encoded-stream-into-pdf-format-php

Comment: @Zabs Where do I get the .pem files from? I have all the wsdl files downloaded within their API section but cannot see this (or the .p12 file that is also mentioned)

Answer (score 5):

<sup>**!** Although you've mentioned you've done most of these steps, I'll detail them anyway to complete the instructions</sup>

#### Installing the CA to the server

- Upload the p12 file to the server (in `/root/Desktop` for example)
- Run the following 3 commands to install

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -out cacert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out mycert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out mykey.pem
```

- Now copy the `*.pem` files into `/etc/ssl/certs`

  - I like to create a subdirectory in here (`mkdir royalmail`)
  - And move the `*.pem` files (`mv *.pem /etc/ssl/certs/certificates`)
- Now create a new file and copy the contents of `mycert.pem` and `mykey.pem` into it (only from `-----BEGIN .... -------` to EOF)

You should have the following files;

[image]

#### Using SOAPClient

Now that the certificates are installed, we can now test the connection (assuming your certificates are in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/certificates/royalmail/shippingv2`)

If you run

```
wget https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding --private-key=/etc/ssl/certs/certificates/royalmail/shippingv2/rm_bundle.pem --private-key-type=PEM
```

You should be able to connect to port 443 (there may be a handshake failure in `OpenSSL` though - at least with my test just now on our staging environment).

We can now instantiate the `SoapClient` using a local copy of the WSDL and specifying the local certificate in the `$options` parameter.

```
$objSoapClient = new \SoapClient('lib/wsdl/royalmail/shipping/ShippingAPI_V2_0_8.wsdl', array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => 1,
    'uri' => 'http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/ship/V2',
    'location' => 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding',
    'local_cert' => '/etc/ssl/certs/certificates/royalmail/shippingv2/rm_bundle.pem',
    'passphrase' => '', //Your passphrase when doing step 1
    'ssl_method' => 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS',
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'trace' => 1
));
```

#### Authentication

In your documentation, you should find a file called `rm_password_digest.php` or something similar, which details how to create the authentication headers.

```
/* The value below should be changed to your password.  If you store the password  */  
/* as hashed in your database, you will need to change the code below to remove hashing */

$password = 'just_my_royalmail_api_password';

/* CREATIONDATE - The timestamp. The computer must be on correct time or the server you are
* connecting may reject the password digest for security.
*/
$CREATIONDATE = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

/* NONCE - A random word. The use of rand() may repeat the word if the server is
* very loaded.
*/
$nonce = mt_rand();

/* PASSWORDDIGEST This is the way to create the password digest. As per OASIS standard
*  digest = base64_encode(Sha1(nonce + creationdate + password)
*  however note that we use a SHA1(password) instead of the password above
*/
$nonce_date_pwd = pack("A*",$nonce) . pack("A*",$CREATIONDATE) . pack("H*", sha1($password));
$PASSWORDDIGEST = base64_encode(
pack('H*', sha1($nonce_date_pwd)));

/* ENCODEDNONCE - Now encode the nonce for security header */

$ENCODEDNONCE = base64_encode($nonce);

/* Now Print all the values - so we can use it for testing with tools like soapui */

print "WS Security Header elements \n";
print "--------------------------- \n";
print 'Nonce = ' . $nonce;
print "\n";
print 'PASSWORDDIGEST= ' . $PASSWORDDIGEST;
print "\n";
print 'ENCODEDNONCE= ' . $ENCODEDNONCE;
print "\n";
print "CREATIONDATE= " . $CREATIONDATE;
```

This will help you build the following in the SOAPHeader

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-0000">
        <wsse:Username>[...]</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">[...]</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">[...]</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>[...]</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Comment: awesome stuff - i will give that a try :)

Comment: Just a quick query - I notice you have the file 'rm_bundle.pem' - what is this? I've only created 3 pem files but noticed you have four?

Comment: Ah, I've put the private key and the certificate into a new file (`rm_bundle.pem`) - let me update my post, sec.

Create a new file and copy the contents of `mycert.pem` and `mykey.pem` into it (only from `-----BEGIN .... -------` to EOF

Comment: Brilliant - I couldn't see where this 'new' file was coming from, thanks really appreciate that

Comment: @hd - thanks dude!! REALLY appreciate the comprehensive answers, we got there in the end! :-)
Royal Mail should hire you guys for this stuff!!

Comment: Hi mate - would you happen to be able to shed any light on this matter (Shipping API related also)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127790/output-a-standard-base64-encoded-stream-into-pdf-format-php

Comment: A big thank-you from another grateful developer. One thing I found was that the Soap call couldn't locate the .pem file in the /etc directories (still gives a could-not-connect-to-host error). I fixed this by storing the .pem file in a local directory.

Comment: This was the missing step that was stopping me from connecting - thanks so much!