# PHP Soap client with ws-security

Tags: php, soap-client, ws-security

How should I implement a SOAP client that consumes a service using ws-security.

I have this binding information

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

To my understanding this a .Net configuration and must be mapped to corresponding definitions in PHP.

The wsHttpBinding to my understanding means that SOAP1.1 must be used, and that seems to be working fine.

However, it the security settings are a big problem.

Is there any PHP library that supports WS Security?

I have tried to add a security header to PHP call:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
```

However, this does not help. Am I missing something?

There are many questions in Stackoverflow on PHP and WS-Security, but I have not found any of them helpful.

EDIT: It turned out that there were problems in the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vanilla PHP [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/soapclient) (and friends) by using [`SoapVar`](http://php.net/soapvar) to set the SOAP headers. For example;

```
$objSoapClient = new \SoapClient([...]);

$strXML = <<<XML
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
XML;
$objAuthVar = new \SoapVar($strXML, XSD_ANYXML);
$objAuthHeader = new \SoapHeader("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", 'Security', $objAuthVar, false);

$objSoapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($objAuthHeader));
```

Comment: Tried that, did not work. The important question is: are you sure it should work? If yes, then the problem is at the other end.

Comment: Yes, it should work. This is my implementation for [Royal Mail sAPIv2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101153/royal-mail-shipping-api-soap-connection-pem-certificates-query/33101532#33101532). Can you output `$objSoapClient->__getLastRequest()` and check it manually? What error are you getting from the remote server?

Comment: I have checked the request manually (many, many times). When calling with what I think is a correct request I get no response whatsoever, ever. If the request is somehow malformed, I get an immediate error response.

Comment: The malformed response is probably from the WSDL file. Have you checked the `$objSoapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders();`? Have you run tests to see if you can reach the remote service? Ie: ping or telnet?

Comment: Malformed request was my own test, in purpose. I have also tested with curl. Same result.