# Couldnt connect to host Royal mail shipping api SOAP

Tags: php, soap

Hello im trying to connect to royalmail shipping api and gettting couldnt connect to host every time. I'm trying to contact royal mail but didnt get proper answer to the issue.

Here is my code:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',1);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',1);

$api_password = "xxxxx";
$api_username = "xxxxxxAPI";
$api_application_id = "xxxxx";
$api_service_type = "D";
$api_service_code = "SD1";
$api_service_format = "";
$clientId='xxxxx';
$clientSecret='xxxxxx';
$api_service_enhancements = "";

$data = new ArrayObject();
$data->order_tracking_id = "";
$data->shipping_name = "Jon Doe";
$data->shipping_company = "SS";
$data->shipping_address1 = "23, Some Road"; 
$data->shipping_address2 = "";
$data->shipping_town = "London";
$data->shipping_postcode = "E1";
$data->order_tracking_boxes = "0";
$data->order_tracking_weight = "1000";    

$time = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
$created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$nonce = mt_rand();
$nonce_date_pwd = pack("A*",$nonce) . pack("A*",$created) . pack("H*", sha1($api_password));
$passwordDigest = base64_encode(pack('H*',sha1($nonce_date_pwd)));
$ENCODEDNONCE = base64_encode($nonce);


$soapclient_options = array(); 
$soapclient_options['cache_wsdl'] = 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE'; 
$soapclient_options['stream_context']= stream_context_create(
                            array(
                                'http' =>
                                    array(
                                        'header'           => implode(
                                            "\r\n",
                                            array(
                                                'Accept: application/soap+xml',
                                                'X-IBM-Client-Id: ' . $clientId,
                                                'X-IBM-Client-Secret: ' . $clientSecret,
                                            )
                                        ),
                                    ),
                            )
                        );
$soapclient_options['trace'] = true;
$soapclient_options['ssl_method'] = 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3';
$soapclient_options['exceptions'] = true;
$soapclient_options['location'] = 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding';

//launch soap client
$client = new SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__) . "/SAPI/ShippingAPI_V2_0_9.wsdl", $soapclient_options);
$client->__setLocation($soapclient_options['location']);

//headers needed for royal mail
$HeaderObjectXML  = '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-000">
              <wsse:Username>'.$api_username.'</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'.$passwordDigest.'</wsse:Password>
              <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'.$ENCODEDNONCE.'</wsse:Nonce>
              <wsu:Created>'.$created.'</wsu:Created>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
       </wsse:Security>';

//push the header into soap
$HeaderObject = new SoapVar( $HeaderObjectXML, XSD_ANYXML );

//push soap header
$header = new SoapHeader( 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $HeaderObject );
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

//build the request
$request = array(
    'integrationHeader' => array(
        'dateTime' => $time,
        'version' => '1.0',
        'identification' => array(
            'applicationId' => $api_application_id,
            'transactionId' => $data->order_tracking_id
        )
    ),
    'requestedShipment' => array(
                                'shipmentType' => array('code' => 'Delivery'),
                                'serviceOccurence' => '1',
                                'serviceType' => array('code' => $api_service_type),
                                'serviceOffering' => array('serviceOfferingCode' => array('code' => $api_service_code)),
                                'serviceFormat' => array('serviceFormatCode' => array('code' => $api_service_format)),
                                'shippingDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                'recipientContact' => array('name' => $data->shipping_name, 'complementaryName' => $data->shipping_company),
                                'recipientAddress' => array('addressLine1' => $data->shipping_address1,  'addressLine2' => $data->shipping_address2, 'postTown' => $data->shipping_town, 'postcode' => $data->shipping_postcode),
                                'items' => array('item' => array(
                                            'numberOfItems' => $data->order_tracking_boxes,
                                            'weight' => array( 'unitOfMeasure' => array('unitOfMeasureCode' => array('code' => 'g')), 'value' => ($data->order_tracking_weight*1000) //weight of each individual item
                                                             )
                                                                )
                                                )
                                )               
);


//if any enhancements, add it into the array
if($api_service_enhancements != "") {
    $request['requestedShipment']['serviceEnhancements'] = array('enhancementType' => array('serviceEnhancementCode' => array('code' => $api_service_enhancements)));
}

//try make the call
try { 
    $response = $client->__soapCall( 'createShipment', array($request), array('soapaction' => 'https://api.royalmail.com/shipping/onboarding') );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //catch the error message and echo the last request for debug
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    echo " REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    die;
}

//check for any errors
if(isset($response->integrationFooter->errors)) { 
    $build = "";

    //check it wasn't a single error message
    if(isset($response->integrationFooter->errors->error->errorCode)) { 
        $build .= $output_error->errorCode.": ".$output_error->errorDescription."<br/>"; 
    } else {
        //loop out each error message, throw exception will be added ehre
        foreach($response->integrationFooter->errors->error as $output_error) { 
            $build .= $output_error->errorCode.": ".$output_error->errorDescription."<br/>";
        }
    }

    echo $build; die;

}

print_r($response);

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
exit;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Could not connect to host REQUEST: xxxxxkAPI xxxxxxx 2016-03-24T02:50:24Z 2016-03-24T02:50:241.0RMG-API-G-01DeliveryDSD12016-03-24Jon DoeSS23, Some RoadLondonE10g1000000
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28986068/628267) with the same error?

Comment: yeah that one uses local cert and api passphrase and they're no longer needed or redundant  instead it uses client id and client secret and i already looked into it but couldn't find out the issue..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you completed the following steps ? (extracted from the Shipping API V2 - Technical User Guide)

1. Sign up on the Royal Mail Developer Portal
2. Create an application
3. Request a subscription for the Shipping API V2
4. Make sure that the subscription was approved by Royal Mail
5. Receive an API Username and API Password from Royal Mail, for connecting to the Shipping API

Further things to check:

- make sure you are using the correct API address (with .net instead of .com)

  - https://api.royalmail.net/shipping/v2
- the transactionId needs to have a valid value, otherwise, if it's empty like in your case ($data->order_tracking_id), you will get the following error: "E0004 Failed Schema Validation"

Moreover, have a look at SoapUI. I found it helpful in debugging my API requests.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Brooks yes ive got valid api details plus client id and client secret and of course the subscription were approved by royal mail but still having issues im sure im missing something but couldnt find it yet!

Comment: @NabarajChapagain Can you please try to use royalmail.net instead of royalmail.com everywhere in the code, and let us know what response you get ?

Comment: Thanks @Tom yeah it finally works my endpoint was wrong.do u know how i get these details
                'api_service_type'      =>'', 
                'api_service_code'      =>'', 
                'api_service_format'    =>'',

Comment: @NabarajChapagain For those fields, check Shipping API Reference Data document at https://developer.royalmail.net/node/70#/
For example, service_type => 'T' is for Royal Mail Tracked

Comment: @NabarajChapagain I've updated the main answer to include the solution that worked for you. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: im using api.royalmail.net/shipping/v2 as royal mail sent that to me.. when i tried the url that you amended it gives me error like "API not found for requested URI"

Comment: Updated ! So you can use https://api.royalmail.net/shipping/v2 for both onboarding and live ?

Comment: yeah i believe so! im still verifying with RM but they;re pain in the ass!!.. take days to reply a single question!

Comment: yeah, same here ! they take so long to reply... anyway, it would be nice if you could post the onboarding address once you get a reply :)

Comment: yeah same url for on boarding and live i reckon!! RM told us that they gonna transfer to live environment once we finished the checking on on boarding environment..

Comment: Working link to up to date reference file https://developer.royalmail.net/sites/developer.royalmail.net/files/rmg_shipping_api_reference_data_v2.09_0.xlsx

Comment: When I am creating my app in royal mail but how to include 10 digit royal mail account number any suggestion for that?